# Connecting to network with terminal

Tags: command-line, networking, wifi

I have a router at home with ESSID of **dlink_home** and **10** digits (0123456789) 64-bit **WEP** encryption of *Open Authentication Type*.

I want to connect to it through terminal with bash commands, I tried

```
ifconfig wlan0 up
iwconfig wlan0 essid dlink_home key s:0123456789
dhclient wlan0
```

When using s: prefix it gives the following error:

> Error for wireless request "Set Encode" (8B2A) :
>       SET failed on device wlan0 ; Invalid argument.

and without it, it doesn't work, as s: prefix is for specifying string key rather than HEX key.

The OS I am running is *Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6*.

Answer (score 5):

#### 1. correct form of the command

Try changing your iwconfig line to this:

```
$ iwconfig wlan0 essid dlink_home key s:0123456789
```

#### 2. wpa_supplicant

If the above command is correct and you're still receiving an error message, make sure that you have the wpa_supplicant package installed.

```
$ yum install wpa_supplicant
```

#### 3. NetworkManager

I'd use NetworkManager over iwconfig when dealing with wireless devices. To connect via command line using NetworkManager in runlevel 3 you can use the following command:

```
 $ nmcli dev wifi connect <name> password <password>
```

#### References

- [Manual Wireless Association - wiki.laptop.org](http://wiki.laptop.org/go/Manual_Wireless_Association)

Comment: edited the post, i do with wlan0, wrote it wrong.

Comment: "wpa_supplicant.x86_64 1:0.7.3-3.el6 @anaconda-RedHatEnterpriseLinux-201206132210.x86_64/6.3" it is already installed. it works when there is no encryption, that is the connection has no password.

Comment: What does `dmesg` and `/var/log/messages` say about the command when it fails?

Comment: i read that iwconfig doesn't work when the password is more than 5 digits, but 10 digits length is fixed in router's settings, i can't change the amount.

Comment: Can you provide a link to where you read that, I've not heard that before, and many of the examples show it with longer than 5.

Comment: i've found the link: http://superuser.com/questions/42460/can-you-explain-how-to-understand-what-the-iwconfig-command-displays-in-ubuntu/353818#353818

Comment: I've never heard this before, but again I use `NetworkManager` for all my wireless setting up. Can you use that instead of what you're doing or do you have to use the actual commands to do this? Also I might be tempted to try using a GUI such as `system-config-network` to setup the device to make sure things are correct vs. attempting it from the command line to start. The GUI will populate the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/*` files for you automatically, so in theory you should only need to do a `ifcfg wlan0 up` and/or `service network start`.

Comment: no, i want to do it within CLI with TTY terminal in init 3 level where networking is enabled. doesn't matter, if it is possible to do so, that is to provide essid and key, and connect to network with **networkmanager**, i would use it instead.

Comment: You can use `NetworkManager` from the command line in runlevel 3! `nmcli`.

Comment: the question is how, can you please provide the code to connect to **dlink_home** with **0123456789** using `NetworkManager`?

Comment: `nmcli dev wifi connect <name> password <password>`